# Como desativar Trigger de todas as tabelas no PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Como desativar a trigger de todas as minhas tabelas no postgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode escrever uma *stored procedure* capaz de habilitar ou desabilitar todas as *triggers* de todas as tabelas de um determinado *schema*, veja só:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fc_habilitar_triggers( nome_schema TEXT, habilitar BOOLEAN )
RETURNS VOID AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE
    tbl RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR tbl IN SELECT schemaname || '.' || tablename AS nome FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = nome_schema
    LOOP
        IF ( habilitar = TRUE ) THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'Habilitando Triggers da Tabela: %', tbl.nome;
            EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || tbl.nome || ' ENABLE TRIGGER ALL';
        ELSE
            RAISE NOTICE 'Desabilitando Triggers da Tabela: %', tbl.nome;
            EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || tbl.nome || ' DISABLE TRIGGER ALL';
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Habilitando todas as *triggers* do *schema* **public**:

```
SELECT fc_habilitar_triggers('public', TRUE );
```

Desabilitando todas as *triggers* do *schema* **public**:

```
SELECT fc_habilitar_triggers('public', FALSE );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tblname DISABLE TRIGGER USER
```

Isso deve resolver o seu problema. Foi marcado como *aceito* [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942258/how-do-i-temporarily-disable-triggers-in-postgresql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) do *SOEN*; lá tem mais algumas alternativas, caso queira dar uma olhada.